# Will the DB dump be consistent if a table is being inserted each second?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want to create a consistent backup (dump) of a PostgreSQL database using `sudo -u postgres pg_dump database_name > db_backup.sql`. There some multiple tables that are being inserted a row each second, therefore these tables are quite huge.

I have two questions:

1. Will I (or ther users, website, …) be able to insert new rows in any of the tables while the dump is being created?
2. Will the dump be consistent?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and yes.

The dump will be a snapshot of the state of the database at the time the dump was started.

However you will not be  able to drop or modify the structure of tables during the dump.